# Sealed inner classes

Tags: java, inheritance, scope, kotlin, inner-classes

I'd like to create a closed universe of classes, where each subclass is an inner class of some outer class. I thought I could use a sealed inner class for the base of the hierarchy, like so:

```
class Outer {
    fun foo(): Int {
        // ...
    }

    inner sealed class InnerBase(val i: Int) {
        fun sharedFunctionality() {
            println(foo() + i)
        } 

        abstract fun doIt()

        inner class Inner1: InnerBase(1) {
            override fun doIt() {
                blah()
                sharedFunctionality()
                bloo()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that

- `Outer` is a proper class, which can have many different instances. Each instance should be able to create `Inner1`'s that will call the right `foo`
- The universe of `InnerBase` subclasses is finite
- `InnerBase` has some instance method, to be used by various `Inner` subclasses, which accesses `Outer`'s non-static method `foo`
- The concrete subclasses of `InnerBase` (e.g. `Inner1`) pass arguments to `InnerBase`'s constructor

However, the problem with this is that I don't know how I can construct a value of type `Inner1` in `Outer`. I was hoping that this would work:

```
class Outer { // continued from above
    fun someMethod() {
        val x: InnerBase = InnerBase.Inner1()
    }
}
```

but this fails with

```
src/InnerSealed.kt:14:27: error: unresolved reference: Inner1
    val x : InnerBase = InnerBase.Inner1()
                                 ^
```

I guess the problem is that `Inner1` is actually an inner class of `Inner`, so I'd need an instance of `Inner` before I could construct an instance of `Inner1`. However, this is not what I'd like; I'd like `Inner` to just be a base class for my `Inner1` etc. classes, with some  functionality which is shared between all subclasses and which access `Outer`'s instance data.

One workaround I've found is to make `InnerBase` non-`sealed`:

```
class Outer {
    fun foo(): Int {
        // ...
    }

    inner abstract class InnerBase(val i: Int) {
        fun sharedFunctionality() {
            println(foo() + i)
        }

        abstract fun doIt()
    }

    inner class Inner1: InnerBase(1) {
        override fun doIt() {
            sharedFunctionality()
        }
    }

    fun someMethod() {
        val x : InnerBase = Inner1()
    }
}
```

But then the subclasses of `InnerBase` are no longer closed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you don't need instances of `Outer` as much as a place to store "`static`" `foo`. Then you need `object`s , not `class`es.

I replaced `class Outer` with `object Outer` and removed `sealed`:

```
object Outer {
    var foo = 42

    sealed class Inner(val i: Int) {
        init {
            println(foo + i)
        }

        class Inner1: Inner(1)
    }

    init {
        val x: Inner = Inner.Inner1()
    }
}
```

Comment: Well in my real program, there's lots of other things happening in `Outer`, and I do indeed plan to have multiple instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

Technically what you are trying to do is this:

```
class Outer {
    var foo = 42
    init {
        val x: InnerBase = InnerBase.Inner1(this)
    }

    sealed class InnerBase(val outer: Outer, val i: Int) {

        fun sharedFunctionality() {
            println(outer.foo + i)
        } 

        abstract fun doIt()

        class Inner1(outer: Outer): InnerBase(outer, 1) {
            override fun doIt() {
                sharedFunctionality()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It provides `Inner1` with an instance of `Outer` without an instance of `Inner`. I am not aware of any clean way of doing this in Kotlin

Comment: Yes, exactly, I'd like to pass `outer` implicitly to `Inner1`. So is there no way to do that? In that case, I think I'd rather go with the open inheritance workaround.

Comment: it is possible if `Inner` is a enum thou

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing a static somewhere? As you don't want to instance a class to use their inner.

Granted I'm not as proficient in Kotlin so I may be horribly wrong.

Comment: Yeah but `Inner` can't be static, since it needs to access `Outer`'s `foo` field.